# ArangoDB - Create AQL INSERT Scripts

Tags: arangodb, aql

I would like to prepare scripts for completing databases. How can I do this?

Something like that:

```
 INSERT { _class: 'Entity', name: 'First'} IN wholesales
 INSERT { _class: 'Entity', name: 'Second' } IN wholesales
 INSERT { _class: 'Entity', name: 'Three' } IN wholesales
 INSERT { _class: 'Entity', name: 'Four' } IN wholesales
```

Answer (score 2):

Only one INSERT operation per collection and query is allowed in AQL.

You can use a loop to make this work however:

```
FOR doc IN [
    { _class: 'Entity', name: 'First'},
    { _class: 'Entity', name: 'Second' },
    { _class: 'Entity', name: 'Third' },
    { _class: 'Entity', name: 'Fourth' }
]
INSERT doc INTO wholesales
```

The documents as well as the collection name can also be passed as [bind parameters](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Fundamentals/BindParameters.html).

Query:

```
FOR doc IN @docs INSERT doc INTO @@coll
```

Bind parameters:

```
{ "docs": [ { ... }, { ... } ], "@coll": "wholesales" }
```

Another way to import data is to use [arangoimport](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Programs/Arangoimport/).